# How to storage previous clicked button?

Tags: android

I'm making a fragment of language game in which will be a matching of the word and the translation. I need to store the previously clicked button and after clicking on another button compare them, and if they match to make them invisible.

**But I'm getting an error:**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.Button.getText()' on a null object reference
```

On the line  `String text = buf.getText().toString();`

**All buttons were defined before.**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (button_prev != 9) {
        if (v.getId() != button_prev) {
            Button buf = (Button) v.findViewById(button_prev);
            String text = buf.getText().toString();

            if (book_array.indexOf(text) - book_array.indexOf((String) ((Button) v).getText()) != 0) {
                // book_array obj contains word and translating

                i--;
                v.findViewById(v.getId()).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                v.findViewById(button_prev).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        }
    }

    switch (v.getId()) {
        // Storage the previously clicked the button in button_prev

        case R.id.button1:
            button_prev = Button_1.getId();
            // button_prev = R.id.button1;
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            button_prev = Button_2.getId();
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            button_prev = Button_3.getId();
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            button_prev = Button_4.getId();
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            button_prev = Button_5.getId();
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            button_prev = Button_6.getId();
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            button_prev = Button_7.getId();
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            button_prev = Button_8.getId();
            break;

        default:
            break;
```

Maybe someone could fix the code? Is there any correct way to store clicked buttons ?

Comment: What is `button_prev`? Which type and how it's initialized/created?

Comment: bro you have to simplify your code as match as you can. the if condition will confuse you. you can separate into multiple lines so can get clearer debug results

Comment: get the declaration and assignment with casting for the button off the if condition for easier error catching.

Comment: @Boken Its integer and initialized before. It shoud store clicked buttons id , and after if condition match I want to use this Id to get Text from button(to check for the presence in the array) and make it invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a POJO for lastclicked view like following to store lastClicked view.

```
public class LastViewClicked {

    private View view;

    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

Now to when you click on any button, update the view Object inside LastClickedView using setView Method and when you need to know what was the last clicked button, you create a switch statement with all Ids as cases and if it matches you can do your operation.

```
    //  This Function gets the last clicked item which has opened up the Alert Dialog for
    //  selection and Updates its UI...
    private void UpdateLastClickedView(int position, ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter) {
        View v = lastViewClicked.getView();
        // cast according to your views...
        AppCompatTextView appCompatTextView = (AppCompatTextView) v;
        //  do your operation...
        switch(appCompatTextView.getId()){
          case R.id.tv1:
              // hide or whatever you want to do...
              break;
          case R.id.tv2:
              // hide or whatever you want to do...
              break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare button_prev as field in your activity or fragment and use getter and setter to access it inside onclick.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your null pointer error may be the result of fragment recreation, which results in the value of button_prev invalid. And, the initial value of button_prev may be the reason.
2. findViewById is a time consuming function. The view binding should be processed once, and once only, in onCreate()
3. It's better if using MVC, MVP or MVVM. User a model to describe your game logic. Focus on the data change, and the UI should be changed with it.